# QTextLayout manual line breaking

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5

I'm trying to render lines one by one using `QTextLayout`. I've tried to set `wrapMode` to `QTextOption::ManualWrap` and call `QTextLine::setNumColumns` for each line but the whole text appears in a single line.

I've also tried to set `wrapMode` to `QTextOption::WrapAnywhere` and this time the text is broken into lines but the empty lines (the ones which consist only of `\n`) are not visible.

I've tried to link against both `Qt4` and `Qt5` with no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq24-textlayouts.html) you have a good example.

Comment: @Tarod the example you've shown uses `setLineWidth` which sets line length in pixels, whereas I need to break at particular points in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `Qt` implements this by creating a new `QTextLayout` for each line. The details can be found in `QPlainTextEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qplaintextedit.cpp.html#_ZN14QPlainTextEdit10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent).

Answer (score 0):

[QTextLine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextline.html) is used for single line text. If you want multiple lines then use [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QTextLine::setNumColumns()` to specify the number of characters which fit on the current line until it breaks. If you know the length of your text lines you can break each line exactly where you want. Newline characters seem to be ignored by `QTextLayout`.

```
QTextOption opt;
opt.setWrapMode(QTextOption::WrapAnywhere);

QStringList text;
text.append("First line");
text.append("Another line");

layout.setText(text.join(""));
layout.beginLayout();

qreal h = 0;
for(const auto& line : text)
{
   QTextLine l = layout.createLine();
   if(!l.isValid()
      break;
   l.setNumColumns(line.length());
   l.setPosition(QPointF(0, h);
   h += l.height();
}

layout.endLayout();
```

Where `layout` is a `QTextLayout` which you could define as a member in your widget class or whatever. But be aware that (at least in Qt 4.8.x) this may not work as expected if you use tabs. I tried to create a layout which had a right and a left tab stop (which can be configured via `QTextOption` and `QTextOption::Tab`) but i couldn't figure out how to get it to set the line breaks correctly. Calculating the line width in pixels isn't easy too, because `QFontMetrics::size()` doesn't support tab stops other than left aligned ones.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by creating a new `QTextLayout` for each line in the text. Instead of a single layout handling all lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

`QTextLine` by `QTextLayout.createLine();`

`QTextLayout` can draw one `QTextBlock`, the **ENTER** charackter or key is create new QTextBlock. Therefor you must draw layout for each block.

The QTextBlock does not contain a `"\n"`character because this character split text to new `QTextBlock`

I uses this Example:

```
class KonuIcerik : public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        return QRectF( 0 , 0 , this->LineWidth , this->height );
    }


    int height;
    int LineWidth;
    int LineCountMod;
    int CallNumber;
    QString metin;
    QFont font;
    QTextEdit* textEdit;

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
               QWidget *widget)
    {

        int y = 0 ;
        CallNumber = 0;
        int PageNumber = 1;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < textEdit->document()->blockCount() ; i++ ){

            QTextBlock block = textEdit->document()->findBlockByNumber(i);
            QTextLayout layout(block);
            layout.setFont(font);

            layout.beginLayout();

            while( true ){
                QTextLine line = layout.createLine();
                if( !line.isValid() ){
                    break;
                }else{
                    if( CallNumber > 37 &&  (CallNumber-37) % LineCountMod == 0 ){
                        y += 300;
                        PageNumber++;
                    }
                    CallNumber++;
                    if( CallNumber == 37 ){
                        y += 300;
                        PageNumber++;
                    }

                    line.setLineWidth( LineWidth );
                    line.setPosition( QPointF( 0 , y ) );
                    y += line.height();
                }
            }
            this->height = y;
            layout.endLayout();
            layout.draw(painter,QPointF(0,0));
        }
    }
    void UPdate(){
        update(-50,-50 , LineWidth+50 , height+50);
    }
};
```

you refer this class and you see the new line if the "\n" contains.
I hope this helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by manually checking for line break character in the `QTextLine`

```
bool ElidedLabelPrivate::doTextLayout(QTextLayout &text_layout, int width,
                                      int height) const {
  /// if height <= 0 - no height limit
  int line_spacing = QFontMetrics(text_layout.font()).lineSpacing();
  qreal height_used = 0;
  qreal width_used = 0;
  const QString &text = text_layout.text();

  while (true) {
    QTextLine line = text_layout.createLine();
    if (!line.isValid()) {
      return true;  // text fits available size
    }
    line.setLineWidth(width);
    // check for line breaks
    const QStringRef line_text =
        text.midRef(line.textStart(), line.textLength());
    if (line_text.contains('\n')) {
      line.setNumColumns(line_text.indexOf('\n') + 1);
    }
    
    line.setPosition(QPointF(0, height_used));
    height_used += line_spacing;
    width_used = std::max(width_used, line.naturalTextWidth());
    int current_pos = line.textStart() + line.textLength();
    bool need_next_line = current_pos < text_layout.text().length();
    bool can_insert_line =
        (height <= 0) || (height_used + line_spacing <= height);
    if (need_next_line && !can_insert_line) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```